# After statustext 200 (OK) I get an error and leaking data in console. Got the reason, but no solution

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a table Brewers, Beers and table BrewerFavorites (favorites from other brewers). Providing a list of a brewers beers gives the error (but also statustText 200). When I add beers (not from my own) to my BrewerFavorites, I have no problem showing them. However when I add my own beers to BrewerFavorites I get the same error.

**Get brewer method (in frontend angular)**

```
get brouwer$(): Observable<Brouwer> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/brouwers/brouwer`).pipe(
      map(
        (list: any): Brouwer => list
      )
    );
  }
```

**Beer model (Angular)**

```
export class Bier {

    private _id;

    constructor(
        private _naam: string,
        private _percentage: number,
        private _kleur: string,
        private _bierSoort: string,
        private _opVat: boolean,
        private _soortGisting: string,
        private _smaak: string,
        private _omschrijving: string,
        private _recent: boolean,
        private _primeur: boolean,
        private _brouwerId?: number,
        private _brouwerNaam?: string,
    ) { }

    static fromJson(json: any): Bier {
        const bier =
            new Bier(json.naam, json.percentage, json.kleur, json.biersoort, json.opVat, json.soortGisting, json.smaak, json.omschrijving, json.recent, json.primeur, json.brouwerId, json.brouwerNaam);
        bier._id = json.id;
        return bier;
    }

    toJson(): any {
        return {
            id: this._id,
            brouwerId: this._brouwerId,
            brouwerNaam: this._brouwerNaam,
            naam: this._naam,
            percentage: this._percentage,
            kleur: this._kleur,
            bierSoort: this._bierSoort,
            opVat: this._opVat,
            soortGisting: this._soortGisting,
            smaak: this._smaak,
            omschrijving: this._omschrijving,
            recent: this._recent,
            primeur: this._primeur
        };
    }
```

**Brewer model (Angular)**
import { Bier } from './bier.model';

```
export class Brouwer {

    private _id;
    private _bieren;

    constructor(
        private _naam: string,
        private _stand: number,

    ) { }

    static fromJson(json: any): Brouwer {
        const brouwer = new Brouwer(json.naam, json.stand);
        brouwer._id = json.id;
        brouwer._bieren = json.bieren.map(bier => bier.fromJson);
        return brouwer;
    }

    toJson(): any {
        return {
            id: this._id,
            naam: this._naam,
            bieren: this._bieren.map(bier => bier.toJson()),
            stand: this._stand
        };
    }
```

The problem is when logged in as Brewer 1. I cant show my own beers or lists containing my own beers. However if I don't have beers of my own in the list I can show them. I would like to also be able to show my own beers.

[image: Error produced]

Comment: It seems like you HTTP response contains an invalid JSON string

Comment: I have read about this, but how does this explain. That calling the same method. When I have a list of beers (who are not my own) it does not produce the error? Ex. There are 3 beers 1, 2, 3. => 1 belongs to brewer1, 2 to brewer2 and 3 to brewer3. If brewer 1 wants to show a list of beers containing beer 1 it produces the error. If brewer1 wants to show a list of beerst without beer 1 in it, it does not produce the error.